# How does a transformation matrix of linear map defined on square matrices look like?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I am quite confused how the transformation matrix looks like in standard basis when the linear map is defined on square matrices.

Given a mapping $T: M_2(\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow M_2(\mathbb{R}) $ defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
T \left( \begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
\right)
=
\begin{bmatrix} 
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
3 & -1 
\end{bmatrix},
\end{equation}

show that $T$ is linear. Find a transformation matrix in standard basis.

I have successfully proved that T is indeed linear. I know that the standard basis of $M_2(\mathbb{R})$ is:

\begin{equation}
e_1=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix},
e_2=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, 
e_3=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, 
e_4=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

Applying T on each of the basis vectors gives me:
\begin{equation}
T(e_1)=\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, 
T(e_2)=\begin{bmatrix} 
3 & -1 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}, 
T(e_3)=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
1 & 2 
\end{bmatrix}, 
T(e_4)=\begin{bmatrix} 
0 & 0 \\
3 & -1 
\end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}

How to proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $T(e_1) = e_1 + 2 e_2 + 0 e_3 + 0e_4$. $T(e_2) = 3e_1 - e_2 + 0 e_3 + 0e_4$. etc. Write out each image of the standard basis in terms of the vector space basis. The coefficients of $T(e_i)$ will form a column of the matrix representation. Your matrix should have 16 elements.

Comment: Wow, it seems so obvious now! Thank you.